# Keep adding subplots to a figure in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I believe that my problem is really straightforward and there must be a really easy way to solve this issue, however as I am quite new with Python, I could not sort it out. I saw multiple answer for cases in which the number of subplots is already known at first, but none apply to my case.

I am doing a foor loop for each unique value in a column, and for every unique value in this specific column, I will make a scatter plot of two of it's features. What I am looking for is the following: The number of subplot will depend on the number of unique values of a certain column on my dataframe, which may vary depending on which file I load with the script. Hence, I want for each loop, add a subplot to the figure. May sound confusing, but with the code that I will post here things will get clearer.

This is naturally a way simpler example than the case in which I am trying to work on:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Column A': [100,200,300,400,500,500,500,300],
'Column B': [1,1,2,2,3,3,0,2], 
'Column C': ["Value_1", "Value_2", "Value_3", "Value_4", "Value_1", 
"Value_2", "Value_3", "Value_4"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Column A','Column B', 'Column C'])

fig = plt.figure()
for val in df['Column C'].unique():
    sdf = df.loc[df['Column C']==val]
    sdf.plot(x='Column A', y='Column B', label='C = {}'.format(val))
```

So, the idea is to add all the created plots, whose quantity may vary depending on the loaded data, to the figure.

Thanks in advance. Wish you the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `subplots`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'Column A': [100,200,300,400,500,500,500,300],
'Column B': [1,1,2,2,3,3,0,2], 
'Column C': ["Value_1", "Value_2", "Value_3", "Value_4", "Value_1", 
"Value_2", "Value_3", "Value_4"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Column A','Column B', 'Column C'])

# The first two argument are the 2 dimension of the matrix of plot
# The figsize param was only to make them bigger in my jupyter notebook

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, len(df['Column C'].unique()), figsize=(17,5))

for i, val in enumerate(df['Column C'].unique()):
    sdf = df.loc[df['Column C']==val]
    sdf.plot(x='Column A', y='Column B', label='C = {}'.format(val), ax=ax[i])
```

And this was my result:
[image]